# How to fix "com.hazelcast.core.OperationTimeoutException: No response for 120000 ms" exceptions in hazelcast?

Tags: java, timeout, hazelcast

I wrote a hazelcast that reads 100M datasets from a file and writes them into a MultiMap. I have 10 (locally running) members. After 70 mio nodes, I see this in my application log:

```
    ERROR 2014-02-19 03:03:56,168 [pool-1-thread-1] HazelcastMaster:190 - Could not finish calculations No response for 120000 ms. Aborting invocation! InvocationFuture{invocation=Invoc
    ationImpl{ serviceName='hz:impl:multiMapService', op=com.hazelcast.multimap.operations.PutOperation@d8b737, partitionId=179, replicaIndex=0, tryCount=250, tryPauseMillis=500, invoke
    Count=1, callTimeout=60000, target=Address[144.76.62.99]:5704}, done=false}
    com.hazelcast.core.OperationTimeoutException: No response for 120000 ms. Aborting invocation! InvocationFuture{invocation=InvocationImpl{ serviceName='hz:impl:multiMapService', op=c
    om.hazelcast.multimap.operations.PutOperation@d8b737, partitionId=179, replicaIndex=0, tryCount=250, tryPauseMillis=500, invokeCount=1, callTimeout=60000, target=Address[144.76.62.9
    9]:5704}, done=false}
            at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.InvocationImpl$InvocationFuture.waitForResponse(InvocationImpl.java:382)
            at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.InvocationImpl$InvocationFuture.get(InvocationImpl.java:294)
            at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.InvocationImpl$InvocationFuture.get(InvocationImpl.java:286)
            at com.hazelcast.multimap.MultiMapProxySupport.invoke(MultiMapProxySupport.java:276)
            at com.hazelcast.multimap.MultiMapProxySupport.putInternal(MultiMapProxySupport.java:52)
            at com.hazelcast.multimap.ObjectMultiMapProxy.put(ObjectMultiMapProxy.java:81)
            at de.komoot.spock.executor.HazelcastMultiMapStorage.add(HazelcastMultiMapStorage.java:31)
            at de.komoot.spock.impl.OsmNodesRepositoryImpl.add(OsmNodesRepositoryImpl.java:22)
            at de.komoot.spock.executor.HazelcastMaster$1.process(HazelcastMaster.java:96)
            at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.pbf2.v0_6.impl.PbfDecoder.sendResultsToSink(PbfDecoder.java:106)
            at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.pbf2.v0_6.impl.PbfDecoder.processBlobs(PbfDecoder.java:163)
            at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.pbf2.v0_6.impl.PbfDecoder.run(PbfDecoder.java:175)
            at de.komoot.spock.impl.PbfUrlReader.run(PbfUrlReader.java:63)
            at de.komoot.spock.executor.HazelcastMaster.call(HazelcastMaster.java:146)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

And this had been send to STDERR:

```
    INFO: [144.76.62.99]:5710 [dev] memory.used=4.3G, memory.free=1.2G, memory.total=5.5G, memory.max=7.0G, memory.used/total=78.83%, memory.used/max=62.20%, load.process=0.00%, load.system=77.00%, load.systemAverage=1144.00%, thread.count=59, thread.peakCount=87, event.q.size=0, executor.q.async.size=0, executor.q.client.size=0, executor.q.operation.size=0, executor.q.query.size=0, executor.q.scheduled.size=0, executor.q.io.size=0, executor.q.system.size=0, executor.q.operation.size=0, executor.q.response.size=0, operations.remote.size=0, operations.running.size=0, proxy.count=2, clientEndpoint.count=0, connection.active.count=9, connection.count=9
    Feb 19, 2014 3:03:46 AM com.hazelcast.spi.Invocation
    WARNING: [144.76.62.99]:5701 [dev] No response for 120000 ms. InvocationFuture{invocation=InvocationImpl{ serviceName='hz:impl:multiMapService', op=com.hazelcast.multimap.operations.PutOperation@d8b737, partitionId=179, replicaIndex=0, tryCount=250, tryPauseMillis=500, invokeCount=1, callTimeout=60000, target=Address[144.76.62.99]:5704}, done=false}
    Feb 19, 2014 3:03:47 AM com.hazelcast.spi.Invocation
    WARNING: [144.76.62.99]:5701 [dev] Asking if operation execution has been started: InvocationImpl{ serviceName='hz:impl:multiMapService', op=com.hazelcast.multimap.operations.PutOperation@d8b737, partitionId=179, replicaIndex=0, tryCount=250, tryPauseMillis=500, invokeCount=1, callTimeout=60000, target=Address[144.76.62.99]:5704}
    Feb 19, 2014 3:03:52 AM com.hazelcast.spi.Invocation
    WARNING: [144.76.62.99]:5701 [dev] While asking 'is-executing': InvocationImpl{ serviceName='hz:impl:multiMapService', op=com.hazelcast.multimap.operations.PutOperation@d8b737, partitionId=179, replicaIndex=0, tryCount=250, tryPauseMillis=500, invokeCount=1, callTimeout=60000, target=Address[144.76.62.99]:5704}
    java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
            at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.InvocationImpl$InvocationFuture.resolveResponse(InvocationImpl.java:432)
            at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.InvocationImpl$InvocationFuture.get(InvocationImpl.java:294)
            at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.InvocationImpl.isOperationExecuting(InvocationImpl.java:476)
            at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.InvocationImpl.access$1300(InvocationImpl.java:36)
            at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.InvocationImpl$InvocationFuture.waitForResponse(InvocationImpl.java:376)
            at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.InvocationImpl$InvocationFuture.get(InvocationImpl.java:294)
            at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.InvocationImpl$InvocationFuture.get(InvocationImpl.java:286)
            at com.hazelcast.multimap.MultiMapProxySupport.invoke(MultiMapProxySupport.java:276)
            at com.hazelcast.multimap.MultiMapProxySupport.putInternal(MultiMapProxySupport.java:52)
            at com.hazelcast.multimap.ObjectMultiMapProxy.put(ObjectMultiMapProxy.java:81)
```

(I redirected the output of all instances into one file).

My question is now: How could I start finding the cause? It worked with a very simple dataset on my dev machine but now that I did a first bigger try I'm lost. What can I do to find the cause of the timeout?

EDIT: I tried to give an example of what I do:

```
    MultiMap<String, Node>  data = instance.getMultiMap("MyMap");

    RunnableSource reader = new PbfUrlReader(input.openStream(), 4);
    Sink master = new Sink() {

            @Override
            public void process(EntityContainer entityContainer) {
                    Node node = ... //something made of entityContainer
                    String key = ... //key generated from entityContainer
                    data.put(key, node);
            }
    };

    reader.setSink(master);
    reader.run();
```

Comment: May we see the code involved in the loading and handling of the datasets? I'll take a guess and say you''re trying to load all 100M sets at once then parse them instead of perhaps using a buffer and parsing as you go.

Comment: Hmm, difficult to reduce it to a few lines but It is a callback function for each read dataset that pushes the data directly into the MultiMap. As I see a hazelcast exception and nodes log a memory usage of 4.3gb I also assume that there nodes already arrived at different nodes. And it seems to fail with the n-th node.

Comment: How much ram do you have available to the JVM? Again I think you need to find a better way to parse the Nodes/dataset. How deep does the Node structure go or is it a flat structure?  Do you know if it is set or variable?

Comment: JVM memory could be an option, but I don't see how the parsing could be the cause. Node is flat. If parsing were bad the master node would fail, not a remote node. Do you use hazelcast?

Comment: Trying to narrow down the scope of the problem: is the cluster stable? So are members joining/leaving the cluster while you are adding data?

Comment: If you can create a test that reproduces the problem, or if you are wiling the share the software with me (I'm a Hazelcast engineer) I can run it locally and see what is going on and try to solve the problem. It could be that this is a problem in the Hazelcast core, and not in your code.

Comment: I think it was a JVM memory issue in the end, At least in later runs I could find a OOM Exception. After profiling a local JVM I found a lot of MapEntry instances - does a MultiMap have one MapEntry per key or per value?

Comment: It should have a MapEntry per MultiMap key. So 10 values for the same key -> should give 1 map entry.

Comment: What overhead should I expect for an entry in a multimap (what does http://www.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/javadoc/com/hazelcast/config/MultiMapConfig.html#setBinary(boolean) change in that context)? Maybe I shouldn't store very small objects? (Class with three double values)